# Anova with repeated replicated design

Tags: r, anova

How can the analysis of repeated replicated design given on this page ( https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115135/repeated-measures-anova-with-replicated-measurements ) be done in R? I can perform ANOVA using aov() but I have some doubts as to the Error term there.

The data is as follows:

```
mydf = structure(list(User = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Mode = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Trial1Time = c(20L, 
    5L, 40L, 10L, 15L, 30L, 13L, 11L, 35L), Trial2Time = c(30L, 
    7L, 25L, 20L, 17L, 35L, 26L, 11L, 38L)), .Names = c("User", 
"Mode", "Trial1Time", "Trial2Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694664/repeated-measures-within-subjects-anova-in-r

Comment: See the help file of `?aov`.

Comment: This is a broad question. What is the model you're considering? What term do you consider would be eligible to be the error term/random effect? What is the number of points per stratum in your actual data? Perhaps you could study Pascal's link, study the subject and ask on crossvalidated.com, since I suspect the nature of the question could be of statistical nature.

Comment: I want to know if the Mode is related to the result values which were obtained at 2 times. What are the alternatives to determine this relation?